# Link existing PFUser Facebook and Twitter with Parse on iOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform

In my iOS application on the initial launch user can sign in with 3 different ways: email/pass, Facebook or Twitter. Registering with each of them will cause to create 3 different users.
Later in my app user should have the possibility to link accounts. For example, if he signed in with email/pass, then he should be able to link Facebook and Twitter.

Parse native -linkInBackground works great in case we have only one user, which is email/pass. But if we will already have Facebook or Twitter account created, the Parse SDK will reply with error, saying that this account is already linked to the social.
At first I thought that I've figured out the workaround:

1. Save the old user data
2. Delete the old user
3. Sign in (not link) with the social (say, Facebook)
4. Fill all the data from the saved user to the new one.

Everything went well with one social, but it appeared that the "authData" field, which is very important in my approach, is not contained in the [PFUser currentUser]. And so despite the fact that all other data is transferred successfully, the authData is not transferred, so that we don't have authentication data of the old user.

The question is: Is there a way to get authData from Parse, or is there any "legal" way to achieve my initial goal of merging (linking) two (three) users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've got it working in a bit different way than I wanted, but looks like it's a quite stable solution.

I've created a custom Parse Class, called, say, MyUser. This class has several fields, like: facebookUser, twitterUser, regularUser, anyOtherSocialUserYouWant. Each of them is a pointer to the _User class.

Now if we are signed as, for example, a regular user, the regular user is created. The same happens with the rest like Twitter or Facebook. By signing in with three different socials we will get three different parse users. That's okay.

Next somewhere in the app, user will press "Link to Facebook" button. We need to save the current user. Next we will make a query for both users if there is a MyClass object with pointers to one of those two users (first is the current user, the second is the new user after sign in). If there is no such MyClass object, we will create one and fill in two fields: regularUser and FacebookUser.

Later if user will try to link to Twitter, we will do the same, and the query will return existing MyClass object, which will have two fields with pointers to regular and Facebook users. We will just add a pointer to the newly signed in Twitter user to that MyClass object.

The only trick is with the data, which should be common for all of the users. It is easy enough with the appropriate query. We will need to do two queries (or one "OR" query, but looks like "OR" query is not working with pointers): first query for required object with "user" field of current user, and the second query (inner query) is for objects with "linkedUser" equal to current MyClass object.

And thus to maintain objects we will need to have two fields on each object: "user" and "linkedUser". First field will be used always, and the second field will be used only after linking.
And yes, after MyClass user is created you will need to check if objects for current user and newly registered user has this fields "linkedUser" and fill it with the MyClass pointer in case of that field is empty.

Hope this will help someone.

P.S.: Dear Parse.com developers, I really appreciate your work, but you should really think about creating the kind of mechanism to merge users.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not access the auth data, just like you can't access the password when the user authenticates directly with email/pass. This is a security requirement and will not change.

Ideally you should add some logic which checks if the new user should be created or if a user with the specified details (probably email address) already exists. If it does then you can reject the new user creation and return a suggestion as to how the user should login.

Comment: I understand that, but is there a way for a workaround? The issue is quite common, and I saw a lot of similar questions without an answer.

Comment: Because you can't access the data, so you can't merge user accounts like that. Discuss with parse if you want a way to do it. Otherwise you need to prevent users doing it or link the users into a group somehow.

Comment: This is an issue I'm having too, and I haven't found a definitive solution in all the threads of read. How can we link an existing PFUser to a Facebook user? The various "link" methods work with PFUser.currentUser(), but (at least in my case) always fail when I provide the user from a query of the Users table. Why? The closest I can get is to create the new user and copy over the data from my existing user (the one found in the Users table). But that won't work with users created by username/password sign-up, since I can't copy the password. Incredibly frustrating.